# How to get the last element name from an xpath provided as a string

Tags: c#, xpath

I'm using C# in visual studio, trying to extract the element name from a string in xpath format that is being provided from a 3rd party library.

```
var xPath = "/TransactionValues/Entities/Entity [Roles/Role='FinancialInstitutionSubstituteCheckContact']/Locations/Location [@Use='Primary']/( normalize-space( concat( PrimaryAddressLine, ' ', SecondaryAddressLine, ', ',City, ', ', State, '  ', PostalCode ) ) )"
```

The element name that I want is "Location" from the above string. Our current method is failing because of the `[@Use='Primary']/(...` part at the end of the string, has an extra forward slash, after the last element name, that is throwing our current method off.

**Current method**

```
xPath.Remove(0, xPath.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

This returns `"( normalize-space( concat( PrimaryAddressLine, ' ', SecondaryAddressLine, ', ',City, ', ', State, '  ', PostalCode ) ) )"`

I've been trying to google it for the past half-hour to find out if there is a **C# class that represents an XPath as a string**, that would allow me to easily extract the last node name perhaps, but all I've found is the `System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator` class which seems to require a full xml document to create an `System.Xml.XPath.XPathExpression` which I might be able to use, but I don't have a full xml document, I just have the string above.

## Edit

We are trying to inject user responses to prompts into an xml file, using the 3rd party provided XPath. The XPath is supposed to specify the location to inject the response. I don't understand what the portion `( normalize-space( concat( PrimaryAddressLine, ' ', SecondaryAddressLine, ', ',City, ', ', State, '  ', PostalCode ) ) )` at the **end** of the XPath is trying to say.

The structure of the Xml would be similar to this:

```
<TransactionValues>
  <Entities>
    <Entity id="Financial_Institution_Substitute_Check_Contact">
      <Locations>
        <Location>
          <City>City</City>
          <PostalCode>Zip</PostalCode>
          <PrimaryAddressLine>Addy1</PrimaryAddressLine>
          <SecondaryAddressLine>Addy2</SecondaryAddressLine>
          <State>State</State>
        </Location>
      </Locations>
      <NonIndividual>
        <Contact>
          <AdditionalInformation>
            <Description>address-phone of bank</Description>
          </AdditionalInformation>
        </Contact>
      </NonIndividual>
      <Roles>
        <Role>FinancialInstitutionSubstituteCheckContact</Role>
      </Roles>
    </Entity>
  </Entities>
</TransactionValues>
```

Comment: This may be a useful reference: https://xpathparser.codeplex.com/

Comment: @DoctorMick It is blowing up because it doesn't know how to parse the left parentheses  after the last index of the "/" character. It looks like it works when the XPath doesn't have an xpath function though, but it's not helping me as-is. I'd have to spend some time figuring out why it is blowing up.